# Switch a single site to a multi-site

Tags: multisite, import

A client of mine wants to switch their single site installation and make it a multi-site one so that they can run an online store on a sub-domain while keeping their existing site on the primary domain.

I've Googled all morning but all I can find is ways to import a single site into an already existing multi-site installation whereas what I need to do is convert a single to a multi.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out [Create A Network on the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)? Essentially:

1. Add `define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );` to your `wp-config.php`
2. Access Tools > Network Setup from the admin menu & follow the instructions.

[image]

Comment: Would this not delete any existing content in the primary site?

Comment: No. But regardless, make a backup!